# Pass a variable value from an IBAction to an IBOutlet

Tags: ios, swift, ibaction, iboutlet

OK,  I am new to this and working slowly through a development course. But I realise if I could crack this one I would be a long way forwards.

I make a post call to a PHP file on my server and return the JSON data. This works. and I can print the variable

```
print("firstNameValue: \(firstNameValue)")
```

I now want to output the value of one variable...firstNameValue into a text field called textField.

I am new to Swift and I am thinking "global variable?". This worked but I want to wait for the response from the HTTP call to complete then update the text field.

I hope you can help. I am very new to OOP and my head is bursting.

```
import UIKit 

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var feel: UITextField!

    @IBAction func anxious(sender: AnyObject) {



        let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://mywebsite.com/Jamesbond.php");

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);

        request.HTTPMethod = "POST";// Compose a query string

        let postString = "firstName=James&lastName=Bond";

        request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil
            {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            // You can print out response object
            print("response = \(response)")

            // Print out response body
            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")

            //Let's convert response sent from a server side script to a NSDictionary object:
            do {
                let myJSON =  try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                if let parseJSON = myJSON {

                    // Now we can access value of First Name by its key
                    let firstNameValue = parseJSON["firstName"] as? String

                    print("firstNameValue: \(firstNameValue)")

                  EDIT::the below two lines solved it.
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.textField.text = firstNameValue}


                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()

    }
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!




    @IBAction func submit(sender: AnyObject) {
        print("hello")
        let a = 9
        let b = 10
        let c = (a*b)
        textField.text="You are a banana \(c)"

    }




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

Comment: Just replace the *I WANT TO  PUT THIS VALUE...* comment with the code to update the text field and you are done.

Comment: Thank you that does not work this is the first thing I tried. 
textField.text="name= \(firstNameValue!)"
this comes back with an error

Comment: It says I neeed to put self. in front like self.textField.text   but when I do this it doesn't generate a compile error but no value is inserted in the field.

Comment: You might dispatch the line to the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

The text field must be updated in the completion handler because `dataTaskWithRequest` works asynchronously.

This code does all necessary optional binding checks and runs the line to update the text field on the main thread.

```
...     
do {
   if let myJSON =  try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject],
      firstNameValue = parseJSON["firstName"] as? String {
         print("firstNameValue: \(firstNameValue)")

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
           self.textField.text = firstNameValue
         }
   }
}
catch {
    print(error)
}
```

The option `.MutableContainers` is not needed at all in this case.

Comment: Thank you I get that... in the end the code below solved it solved it but from what you are saying there is some redundant code here.

Comment: Nearly there...see edit on main quiestion for solution. Thanks for you help